# managing H2 connection pool in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, connection-pooling, h2, zend-studio

Eclipse uses H2 DB to store code informations, needed to autocompletion / inferencing / search etc.

When database grows bigger (like, in my case, 1.5 G) it's getting slower. When many IDE thread are trying to connect to db, they are forced to wait, because connection pool is limited by default, AFAIK, to 10 connections.

Is there is any way to change in eclipse (Zend Studio 12.5, Eclipse 4.x) limit of connections or maybe even use different CP library ?